# Struggling to remove FOUC (Flash Of Unstyled Content) when using Webpack

Tags: javascript, css, sass, webpack, bundler

I have bundled my app code using webpack 2. Used require statement on my main module to embed an SCSS file.

```
require('./styles/styles.scss');
```

While things work fine in all browsers, there is a FOUC (Flash Of Unstyled Content) visible when loading the application.

Is it the way all webpack modules load since CSS files are injected dynamically to header or am I doing something wrong in webpack config?

Here is a snippet of webpack config - loader section:

```
{
    test: /\.scss$/,
    loaders: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader?sourceMap', 'sass-loader?sourceMap' ]
}
```

Albeit this isn't causing any side effects but would be better if avoided.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right now your styles are baked into the JS files. In your case, the browser takes a while to parse the javascript and only after processing it can apply the styles to the page. That is causing the FOUC.

To cope with this problem [ExtractTextPlugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin) was developed. Basically what it does is it takes out the css specified and puts it in a separate css file. A basic configuration would look like:

```
const plugin = new ExtractTextPlugin({
  filename: '[name].[contenthash:8].css',
});

module: {
      rules: [ {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: plugin.extract({
            use: 'css-loader',
            fallback: 'style-loader',
          })
       }]
},
plugins: [ plugin ]
```

Then you must attach the generated file to your HTML page if you're not using [html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin). By linking generated file in  section you will get rid of FOUC.

Comment: ExtractTextPlugin has been deprecated and is now "mini-css-extract-plugin"